# Provide json post data in form based authentification

Tags: json, zap

ZAP provides a way to turn a login (POST) request into a logging pattern (through the "mark as ..." in context menu).

When the data is something like `"user=toto&psswd=t@T°"`, it will translate it into

`"user={%username%}&psswd={%password%}"`

after you told it about the keywords `user` and `psswd`.

But when your data is a json object such as `{"user":"toto","psswd":"t@T°"}`,
and even though the content-type of the original request specifies it, ZAP will be unable to detect what keyword can be used, and will propose `{"user":"toto","psswd":"t@T°"}` as both username and password keyword... thus preventing you from defining a correct login pattern.

Do you know of a tip to process through form-based authentication with ZAP?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately at this time there is an outstanding feature request for handling authentication via a JSON Object: https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/issues/2439

One alternative is to [record a scripted authentication](https://www.coveros.com/scripting-authenticated-login-within-zap-vulnerability-scanner/).

---

*Update*:

The previously discussed functionality is now available: https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/pull/4624

If you want to use it, you'll either have to use a weekly: https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/wiki/Downloads#zap-weekly

Or, wait for the next full release (likely 2.8.0).

The corresponding PR to update the help content for the new JSON Authentication functionality is here: https://github.com/zaproxy/zap-core-help/pull/188/files if you want to check it out.

You set it up the same way you would for form based authentication. Make sure you define a Logged-in or Logged-out Identifier (or both). Here's some screenshots to help you along:

Manually configure the Authentication for your Context:
[image: Context Authentication Settings]

Use the Site Tree Context menu(s) to set it up:
[image: Flag a JSON request as the Context's "Login Request"]

[image: Select the associated username and password fields]

Here's an additional help link that might assist you in getting authentication setup: https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/wiki/FAQformauth

Comment: I should have looked further into issues. Thanks for pointing out the request and the alternative as well!

Comment: Hey Marvin, the functionality is now a available. I've updated the answer.

Comment: That's awesome! I'll try it asap! Thanks for the information